# Появляется ошибка IllegalStateException: Fragment already added при переходе между элементами меню BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, bottom-navigation-view

У меня есть activity, в которой расположено **BottomNavigationView** с 3мя элементами меню. При открытии приложения запускается стартовый фрагмент в котором расположен **ViewPager2**, в котором по свайпу меняются фрагменты (**но не те**, что в **BottomNavigationView**). После перехода с главного фрагмента на второй или третий через **BNV** и при возвращении обратно на главный, тоже посредством переключения айтема **BNV** приложение выкидывает ошибку **IllegalStateException: Fragment already added**. Но если возвращаться через кнопку Back на главный фрагмент с **ViewPager2**, то ошибки нет. Навигация в приложении устроена через **Navigation**.

Фрагмент для **ViewPager2**:

```
class ViewPagerFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false)
        val adapter =
            ViewPagerAdapter(
                fragments,
                requireActivity().supportFragmentManager,
                lifecycle
            )
        view.view_pager.adapter = adapter
        return view
    }
}
```

Мой адаптер для **ViewPager2**:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(
    list: ArrayList<Fragment>,
    fm: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fm, lifecycle) {

    private val fragmentList = list

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }
}
```

И фото моей **навигации**, в которой при переключении этих 3х фрагментов и появляется **ошибка**
[image: нафигация]

**Сама ошибка:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.schooljournal, PID: 10704
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.setInitialSavedState(Fragment.java:709)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.ensureFragment(FragmentStateAdapter.java:269)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:175)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FragmentStateAdapter.java:67)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onLayout(ViewPager2.java:527)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1656)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1656)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Кажется нашел ошибку. Она заключается в том, что в Адаптере в методе createFragment(position: Int): Fragment все мои фрагменты сразу присоединяются к моей активити, и когда я перключаюсь на другой элемент из BNV, а потом перехожу обратно на страницу с VIewPager2, мои фрагменты пытаются заново присоединиться. Но сделать, чтобы оно уже брало из стэка присоединенные фрагменты, я пока не знаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Выкладываю рабочее решение:**

Во фрагменте *ViewPagerFragment* в методе onCreate нужно каждый раз инициализировать мой *ArraList* с фрагментами, чтобы они заново присоединялись к активити при переходе на фрагмент с **ViewPager2**:

```
class ViewPagerFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var adapter: ViewPagerAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        fragments = createFragments()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false)
        adapter =
            ViewPagerAdapter(
                fragments,
                requireActivity().supportFragmentManager,
                lifecycle
            )
        view.view_pager.adapter = adapter
        return view
    }

    private fun createFragments(): ArrayList<Fragment> {
        val fragments = arrayListOf<Fragment>()
        for (i in 1..52) {
            fragments.add(MainPageFragment.newInstance(i))
        }
        return fragments
    }
}
```

До этого *ArrayList* с фрагментами инициализировался **всего один раз** при запуске приложения и никогда не менялся.
Сам массив fragments у меня хранится в классе Utils. Не знаю насколько такое решение правильное с точки зрения памяти приложения, и что точно происходит со старыми фрагментами, но оно рабочее для меня. Надеюсь, кому-то помог!